# inner join between two tables shows an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with inner join statement in mysql. I have two table one is information and other is student.What i want when value of lname in student table and value in lname in information table are same then select fname from information.I got error...

```
$grad_stu1 = mysql_query("SELECT information.fname FROM information INNER JOIN student ON student.lpatel == information.lname;") or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Comment: MySQL's (and most other RDBMS) equality operator is `=` not `==`.

Comment: error message should have told you that. Could you check if the error message is clear enough ?

Comment: For future reference, please _read_ error messages and if they seem cryptic google them, and if they still are troubling you at least post the message along with your question.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Also, always include error messages in your post. Just saying "I got [an] error" does not tell us much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use single `=` in `MySQL`

```
SELECT   `information`.fname 
FROM     `information` 
         INNER JOIN student 
             ON student.lpatel = `information`.lname
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `=` not `==`:

```
$grad_stu1 = mysql_query("SELECT information.fname FROM information 
                          INNER JOIN student ON 
                          student.lpatel = information.lname;") 
                          or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```